# Visual Studio, convert Gridview columns to rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I want to convert the gridview function to rows. I have a header saying "Content Manager" and I have their username displayed below it. I want the username to be able to be displayed to the right of the "content manager" text. Thank you!

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource19" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IntranetDB %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [username], [grouping], [isContentManager], [CMRegion] FROM [Permissions] WHERE (([grouping] = 'marketing') AND ([isContentManager] = 'yes'))">
          
                </asp:SqlDataSource>    
                                            
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource19">
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Content Manager" SortExpression="username" />
         
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
                                            <ej:Grid ID="Grid1" runat='server'></ej:Grid>
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Read about pivoting, and update tags.

Comment: I believe it's ASP. sorry im new to this, im an intern.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DataList` and set its [RepeatDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_DataList_RepeatDirection) to `Horizontal`.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="float: left">
        <asp:Label runat="server">Content Manager: </asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            RepeatLayout="Table"
            RepeatColumns="0" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("UserName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

    </div>
</form>
```